# Painting JPanels from within a another one/getting a simple game engine to work

Tags: java, swing, game-engine

Here's my ordeal. I'm trying to make a simple platformer, where a ball moves around the screen and can jump around to different platforms. For now, I'm just trying to get a ball to move around on the screen with proper class structure and encapsulation. My game structure looks like this:
**Game Frame**
Creates JFrame
Runs engine as content pane

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameFrame {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");
        Ball ball = new Ball(125, 250, 25, 0, 0, 2);
        BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel(ball);
        Engine engine = new Engine(ball, ballPanel);
        window.add(engine);
        window.add(ballPanel);
        window.setContentPane(engine);
        window.getContentPane().setSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
        window.getContentPane().add(ballPanel);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        window.addKeyListener(engine);
    }

}
```

**Engine**
Implements listeners
Updates values of position, motion, and size for ball
Calls a "step" function for the ball on a 60fps timer

```
    `package main;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Engine extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

  private boolean spacePressed = false, rightPressed = false, leftPressed = false;
  private boolean offGround = true;
  private Ball b;
  private ArrayList<Platform> platforms;
  private BallPanel bP;
  private ArrayList<PlatformPanel> pPs;


    public Engine(Ball ball, BallPanel ballPanel, ArrayList<Platform> ps, ArrayList<PlatformPanel> pps){
        b = ball;
        platforms = ps;
        bP = ballPanel;
        pPs = pps;
        setFocusable(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, this);
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public Engine(Ball ball, BallPanel ballPanel){
        b = ball;
        bP = ballPanel;
        setFocusable(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, this);
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

//  public void checkCollision(Platform p, Ball b){
//      //right side of ball with left side of platform
//      if(linesIntersect(b.getX()+b.getR(), b.getY()-b.getR(), b.getX()+b.getR(), b.getY()+b.getR(), p.getX(), p.getY(), p.getX(), p.getY()+p.getH())){
//          b.setVx(0);
//      } //left side of ball with right side of platform 
//      else if(linesIntersect(b.getX()-b.getR(), b.getY()-b.getR(), b.getX()-b.getR(), b.getY()+b.getR(), p.getX()+p.getW(), p.getY(), p.getX()+p.getW(), p.getY()+p.getH())){
//          b.setVx(0);
//      }//bottom side of ball with top of platform
//      else if(linesIntersect(b.getX()-b.getR(), b.getY()+b.getR(), b.getX()+b.getR(), b.getY()+b.getR(), p.getX(), p.getY(), p.getX()+p.getW(), p.getY())){
//          b.setVy(0);
//      }//upper side of ball with bottom of platform 
//      else if(linesIntersect(b.getX()-b.getR(), b.getY()-b.getR(), b.getX()+b.getR(), b.getY()-b.getR(), p.getX(), p.getY()+p.getH(), p.getX()+p.getW(), p.getY()+p.getH())){
//          b.setVy(0);
//      }
//  }

    public void update(){
    b.setVy(b.getVy()+b.getAcc());
    if(spacePressed && !offGround){
      b.setVy(b.getVy()-20);
      b.setY(b.getY()+b.getVy());
      offGround = true;
    }
    if(leftPressed){
      b.setX(b.getX()-b.getVx());
    }
    if(rightPressed){
      b.setX(b.getX()+b.getVx());
    }
    if(b.getY() < 250){
      b.setY(b.getY()+b.getVy());
    }
    else{
      b.setVy(0);
      b.setY(250);
      offGround = false;
    }
  }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
        bP.step();
//      for(PlatformPanel pP : pPs){
//          pP.step();
//      }
    }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
  {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
      spacePressed = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      rightPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      leftPressed = true;
    }

  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
      spacePressed = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      rightPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
      leftPressed = false;
    }
  }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**Ball**
Stores values for position, motion, and size
Has setter/getter methods for accessibility

```
    package main;

public class Ball implements Collidable {

    private int ballX, ballY, ballR, Vx, Vy, acc;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int r, int vx, int vy, int a){
        ballX = x;
        ballY = y;
        ballR = r;
        Vx = vx;
        Vy = vy;
        acc = a;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return ballX;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return ballY;
    }

    public int getVx(){
        return Vx;
    }

    public int getVy(){
        return Vy;
    }

    public int getAcc(){
        return acc;
    }

    public int getR(){
        return ballR;
    }

    @Override
    public void setX(int x) {
        ballX = x;

    }

    @Override
    public void setY(int y) {
        ballY = y;

    }

    public void setVx(int x){
        Vx = x;
    }

    public void setVy(int y){
        Vy = y;
    }

    public void setAcc(int a){
        acc = a;
    }


}
```

**BallPanel**
Paints the ball using its values

```
    package main;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BallPanel extends JPanel
{
  private Ball b;


  public BallPanel(Ball ball){
    b = ball;
  }

  public void step(){
    System.out.println("step working");
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    System.out.println("PaintComponent working");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(b.getX(), b.getY(), 2*b.getR(), 2*b.getR());
  }

}
```

However, even though PaintComponent is being called, nothing is being drawn in the frame. Why is this? Should my game structure be changed? My friend suggested not having a BallPanel and just drawing the ball from within the engine. Would this work better? I did read something about paintComponent only being called on components within the content pane (which is why i tried adding ballPanel to it)

Comment: `window.add(ballPanel);
        window.setContentPane(engine);` Adding two components with no constraint to a `BroderLayout`? BTW `public class Engine extends JPanel ..` Why does the engine extend `JPanel`?

Comment: Engine extends JPanel so that it can be its own Key and Action Listener, also i tried painting the ball from the engine by redefining paintComponent within engine and calling repaint in update, and that worked except that repaint called both engine's paintComponent and BallPanel's